# Ошибки с кодировкой

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте, есть sql таблица `news`, когда добавляю новость с русскими буквами, в ответ получаю такие символы:

> ????????????????? ???????????????? ???

А с английскими буквами все нормально. Из-за чего это может быть?  Кодировка сайта `charset=windows-1251`.

Comment: Кодировка данных БД какая?

Comment: utf8_general_ci, изменил на 1251 ничего не получилось, и вернул на прежнюю кодировку (utf8_general_ci)

Comment: Помимо кодировки БД есть еще кодировка таблиц, насколько помню - есть даже кодировка полей таблиц. Вообще - вопрос данного характера неоднократно обсуждался в интернете, в т.ч. здесь. Каждый раз ТС думал что он особенный и у него не работает что-то другое (по другому и т.д. и т.п.), хотя, возможно, ему тупо влом разбираться, ну да суть не в этом. Суть в том, что ничего нового вы не увидите и если самые простые варианты вас не спасли - скорее всего вам все-равно прийдеться разбираться самим, нравиться вам это или нет. (PS: если вы новичек - это не меняет абсолютно ничего)

Comment: AlexWindHope, спасибо, после прочтения вашего комментария, я проверил и изменил все кодировки таблиц и полей, теперь все отлично работает! Благодарю!

Comment: @Максуд - поздравляю, вы не безнадежны :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте перед запросами к базе данных делать

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'cp1251'");
```

Comment: Поставил, без изменений, и за одно проверил phpmyadmin, там тоже в ячейке title такие же символы что выше

Comment: В таблице только что заметил, что где "Сравнение" там стоит кодировка: latin1_swedish_ci, как его изменить ?

Answer (score 1):

Если это MS SQL Server, то надо установить язык соединения.
SET LANGUAGE 'русский'

Comment: Это MySql, хостинг АйпиХостер.

Comment: C MySql не знаком, но если поможет. В MS SQL все региональные параметры (язык,дата и пр. устанавливаются только для текущего соединения - SET LANGUAGE 'русский')

Answer (score 1):

От того, что вы поменяли кодировку в таблице, кодировка строк не изменится, теперь необходимо конвертировать все строки в нужную кодировку. Для лучшего понимания темы - [Кодировки в MySQL](http://www.anton-pribora.ru/articles/mysql/mysql-charsets/)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй сам файл который в котором прописан коннект к БД преобразовать в UTF - 8 без BOM.
Так же проверь кодировку самих полей в БД.

**Добавлено.**

Пробуй вот так:

```
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "db_user", "xxxxxxxx") or die("Ошибка при подключении к хосту" . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db_name", $conn) or die ("Нет такой схемы" . mysql_error());
mysql_query ("SET NAMES 'CP1251'"); // устанавливаем кодировку для страницы
```

Можно вообще вот такое попробовать:

```
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $conn);
```

Comment: Сделал, не помогает :(

Comment: Пробуй вот так:
$conn = mysql_connect("localhost", "db_user", "xxxxxxxx") or die("Ошибка при подключении к хосту" . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("db_name", $conn) or die ("Нет такой схемы" . mysql_error());
mysql_query ("SET NAMES 'CP1251'"); // устанавливаем кодировку для страницы

Можно вообще вот такое попробовать: 
mysql_query("SET character_set_results = 'utf8', character_set_client = 'utf8', character_set_connection = 'utf8', character_set_database = 'utf8', character_set_server = 'utf8'", $conn);

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess, AddDefaulCharset cp1251

Comment: Internal Server Error, это скорее всего в phpmyadmin'е нужно поправить, ибо если даже изменить таблицу новостей (текста) то все равно появляются такие символы: ????????????

Comment: в браузере Firefox проверьте, Меню->Вид->Кодировка->
Попробуйте разные кодировки поставить, исчезнуть ли знаки ???????, если да, то при каком кодировке? И т .д.
Думаю, у вас кодировкой все правильно, только данные в базе не в той кодировке сохранены.

Comment: Данные в базе? Где это проверить? И нету смысла проверить через браузер кодировку страницы, так как php получает с бд такие символы. Если я неправ, то поправьте меня.